# Any alternative way to solve this?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $4$ tins of fruit be chosen from a supermarket offering $10$ varieties if AT LEAST $2$ of the tins are of the same variety?

I solved this way:
At least $2$ tins of the same variety means, in my opinion:

$2$ same & $2$ different OR $2$ same & $2$ same but of another variety different from the first OR 
$3$ same & $1$ different OR 
All $4$ are the same.

So the required $= 10 \times {9\choose 2} + (10 \times 9)/2 + 10 \times 9 + 10 = 505$ (which is the same answer @ the back of the book)

However, I'd like to solve it another way by taking advantage of the word "AT LEAST" by using the strategy:
How many selections to be made without restriction - how many ways I can do the opposite of "at least $2$ varieties are the same"

But I've got $2$ problems:

1st) How many selections to be made without restriction is ${10\choose 4} = 210$ which is smaller than $505$ but I need to still subtract off some number from $210$.

2nd) I don't know how to compute the opposite of "at least $2$ varieties are the same"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Selecting $4$ tins from $10$ kinds is a "stars and bars" problem: In how many ways can you arrange $9$ bars (separating the flavors) and $4$ stars (standing for the selected tins) in a row. The answer is ${13\choose 9}={13\choose 4}$. Among all these selections the ones where actually $4$ different flavors have been selected are forbidden; there are ${10\choose 4}$ of them.

It follows that the number $N$ you are looking for is given by
$$N={13\choose 4}-{10\choose 4}=715-210=505\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Without restriction would mean 10 choices for the first tine, 10 choices for the second tin, ... so 10*10*10*10 *arrangements*. You'll then need to consider how many combinations are possible.

The opposite of needing at least two tins of the same variety would be having no tins of the same variety i.e. all tins are different varieties.